# Как рисуется такой блок

Tags: html, css, svg

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сверстать такой блок со стрелочками? на HTML+СSS
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По совету Meth0d получилось сделать такое (как сделать разделительные линии?)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все очень просто https://cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator/

Comment: Почти то что нужно, а как там бордер задать который стрелочкой?

Comment: `clip-path` засовываете в контейнер, а контейнеру задаете, высоту, ширину, бордер и все что заблагорассудится. А, понял. Вам просто три одинаковые контейнера нужны и правые два с отрицательным `margin-left`. В реальном проекте я как то раз подобное реализовывал через псевдоэлемент

Comment: Лучше такое, наверное, рисовать в svg любым векторным редактором

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Реализация довольно тривиальная - псевдоэлементы с трансформацией:

```css
.blockArrow {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px; width: 100px;
  margin-left: 19px;
}
.blockArrow::before,
.blockArrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px; z-index:-1;
  height: 50%; width: calc(100% + 20px);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fa08;
}
.blockArrow::before {
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform: skewx(20deg);
}
.blockArrow::after {
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: none;
  transform: skewx(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="blockArrow">blockArrow 1</div><div class="blockArrow">blockArrow 2</div>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что скомпанованные псевдоэлементы "отклеиваются" друг от друга на уровне суб-пикселей при масштабировании. Измените масштабирование в браузере на 125%, 133%, 150% и вы увидите суб-пиксельные артифакты рендеринга на некоторых масштабах.

Comment: @NoSkill: Хром на масштабах 125% и 150% отображает всё корректно (133% даже не представляю, как выставить :-) А вообще, проблема эта известная. Если заливка непрозрачная, то решается просто - сдвигом одного из псевдоэлементов на 1px.

Comment: У меня включено масштабировние в самой Windows и я вижу артефакты рендеринга даже в Хроме. В других браузерах тоже на разных масштабах. Свинуть на 1px можно, но не согласен, что это хорошее и простое решение. Бывает, что элемент полупрозрачный... не в данном случае конечно...

Comment: @NoSkill: я постоянно требую от вопрошающих указания полных вводных для задач, но... им кажется несущественным заострять внимание на такой мелочи, как прозрачность, например. Следовательно, каков вопрос - таков ответ.

Answer (score 5):

### Svg отлично подходят для создания фигур в html

- Используйте **`polygon element`** для рисования фигур.
- **`Text element`** для  описания ссылки.
- **`A element`** для создания ссылки.

```css
#arrow-menu a polygon {
  fill: #888;
  stroke: #222;
}
#arrow-menu a:hover polygon {
  stroke: #222;
  fill: black;
}
#arrow-menu a:hover text {
  fill: cornflowerblue;
}
#arrow-menu a {
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="arrow-menu" viewBox="-1 -1 112 22" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 0,0"></polygon>
    <text x="1.5" y="11.5">Menu link</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon transform="translate(22)" points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 5,10 0,0"></polygon>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon transform="translate(44)" points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 5,10 0,0"></polygon>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon transform="translate(66)" points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 5,10 0,0"></polygon>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [How to make a div with arrowlike side without css border tricks? @Persijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38038730/7394871)

Comment: А можно ли сделать, чтобы текст растягивал контейнеры, но визуально толщины линий были бы одинаковыми?

Comment: @NoSkill 1. В svg можно растягивать только все элементы одновременно. За это отвечает viewBox и viewport. Чтобы текст при увеличении длины (большее количество слов), растягивал контейнер, то это можно сделать только с помощью метода JS `getComputedTextLength();`, затем подставить полученную длину в path фигуры контейнера.    2. Чтобы толщина линий не изменялась при увеличении [vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect)

Comment: Это уже излишне сложно... В таком случае вариант с псевдоэлементами предпочтительней, а вариант с SVG в случае визуально- и масштабно-одинаковых элементов.